# apigen - ERROR: the server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request

Tags: php, documentation

I just installed [apigen](http://apigen.org/) 2.7.0 and tried to generate some documentations. I tried to run apigen from within NetBeans as well as from the command line with the `--debug` parameter, but I always get the same error output:

```
ERROR: the server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

For more information turn on the debug mode using the --debug option.
```

I also tried the latest version of apigen from github, but still I get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Set default time zone in your `php.ini`. This will be solved in 2.7.1 very early.

Comment: I'm running MAMP on my local machine and the timezone ist set to `date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"`. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Linux. Did you run it with --debug option as said? What is the output of:

```
$ apigen --version --debug
```

Also, check the IDE's log file. 
Nevertheless, this is most probably a problem with Netbeans **permissions**. Running it as sudo should solve the problem:

```
sudo netbeans
```

In case you don't want to run it as a privileged user, check the logs and change permissions for each denied write operation (many of them indeed).

All in all, you might also want to check [phpdocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/). Or python :)